# When I want to save my table, db.savechanges() gives an error because that data has been used before

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation

in the database connected to my .NET MVC project, one of the tables contains a unique key. How do I check if this value has been entered before or how can I show the error message if the `db.savechanges()` operation fails?

///My Controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Hayvan_id,Kupe_no,Kilo,Irk,Detay,Lokasyon,Turu,Hisse,Kayit_Tarihi,fiyat")] Hayvan_Tablosu hayvan_Tablosu)
    {
        var SaveTrue = db.SaveChanges();
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Hayvan_Tablosu.Add(hayvan_Tablosu);
            db.SaveChanges(); ///I am getting the error here.
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        return View(hayvan_Tablosu);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can execute your operation in try/catch statement:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "Hayvan_id,Kupe_no,Kilo,Irk,Detay,Lokasyon,Turu,Hisse,Kayit_Tarihi,fiyat")] Hayvan_Tablosu hayvan_Tablosu)
{ 
    try {
      var SaveTrue = db.SaveChanges();
      if (ModelState.IsValid)
      {
        db.Hayvan_Tablosu.Add(hayvan_Tablosu);
        db.SaveChanges(); ///I am getting the error here.
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
      }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        // Do something with your error.
        // E.g.:
        return View(new { Error = true, Message = e.Message });
    }
    return View(hayvan_Tablosu);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the return value from `db.SaveChanges()`

```
int val = db.SaveChanges();
if(val > 0)
{
 // the value was entered
}
else
{
 // error message
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is always best practice to check in the beginning whether the `UNIQUE KEY` is already present or not.

```
if(db.Hayvan_Tablosu.Any(x=>x.UniqueColumn == hayvan_Tablosu.UniqueColumn))
{
ModelState.AddModelError("", "UniqueColumn Already Exists");
return View(hayvan_Tablosu);
}
else
{
//add to list and call save changes.
}
```